# Can I install magento in folder but view in domain root?

Tags: install

I have a Magento installation in /store  but I actually want the store to be visible from / without cluttering up my domain root.

Is this possible without 301 directs?

I know in Wordpress it's pretty simple, but I'm not overly familiar with Magento.

Thanks

EDIT:

I've tried using a rewrite e.g

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co.uk$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/$1
```

That works for everything except the home page i.e works with /index.php but not /

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html             
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the correct way of doing it in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749733/how-to-direct-magento-installation-path-in-subfolder-to-main-domain-name

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with redirects but it's not a very elegant solution.

If your domain root is a Magento store, I do not see how it will clutter up the root directory?

If you are using a hosting control panel like cPanel, I understand that it may be messy when you have Subdomains and/or Addon Domains in the root "public_html" or "www" directory along with all the website files and for such cases there's actually a better solution, which is to set the document root for the Subdomains and/or Addon Domains to a folder which is outside of "public_html" or "www".

Comment: My magento store in a folder in the domain root called /store. I also have a wordpress installation in /blog and multiple other directories in the domain root too. I don't want to move magento to / as I don;t want all the magento directories mixed up with everything else when I'm file browsing.